# how to display or use an image received from Android phone on the server 

Tags: java, android, image, jakarta-ee, servlets

I am sending an image from android phone to the server which hanldes it ,but now i am confused on how to use the image in the server

my code for android phone which sends the image is

```
                            Log.i("sAMPLE","Info:" );
                //String postURL = HOST_SERVER_URL + HOST_PHOTO_UPLOAD_URI;
                String postURL ="http://10.0.2.2:8080/SimpleServlet/simple-servlet";//server URL
                HttpClient httpClient = new DefaultHttpClient();
                HttpPost postRequest = new HttpPost(postURL);

                ByteArrayBody bab = new ByteArrayBody(imageBytes, "file_name_ignored");
                MultipartEntity reqEntity = new MultipartEntity(HttpMultipartMode.BROWSER_COMPATIBLE);
                reqEntity.addPart("source", bab);
                postRequest.setEntity(reqEntity);

                HttpResponse response = httpClient.execute(postRequest);
```

and my code which handles the image in the server is like this

```
        protected void doPost(HttpServletRequest req, HttpServletResponse resp)
                throws ServletException, IOException {
    boolean isMultipart = ServletFileUpload.isMultipartContent(req);
    System.out.println("Before Mutlipart");
    if(!isMultipart)
        throw new ServletException("upload using multipart");

    ServletFileUpload upload = new ServletFileUpload(fif);
    upload.setSizeMax(1024 * 1024 * 10 /* 10 mb */);
    List<FileItem> items;
    try {
        items = upload.parseRequest(req);
    //}// catch (FileUploadException e) {
      //  throw new ServletException(e);
    } catch (FileUploadException e) {
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
        throw new ServletException(e);
    }

    if(items == null || items.size() == 0)
        throw new ServletException("No items uploaded");

    FileItem item = items.get(0);
    //BufferedImage Img=item.getString();
    System.out.println(item.getContentType());
    byte[]data=item.get();
```

now how do i use the byte array to display the image on the server or use to edit the image with some other stuffs like string,other image etc.

Comment: how should i use the data received from phone on the servlet as an image so that i can edit it..the image i received is in the item variable

Comment: What do you mean by edit it? Do you want to crop?, resize? Manipulate?

Comment: manipulate..i want to add some text description to it to it..

Comment: Just to be sure; You want to modify the image by putting text on it. For example a name, copyright footer or something like that in the corner or something? What do you want to do with it afterwards? Store it on disk? Display it back to the user who posted it?

Comment: after adding some description i need to send it back to the phone application which would post it on to facebook

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think this should work for you...

http://www.mkyong.com/java/how-to-convert-byte-to-bufferedimage-in-java/

on the server side (imageInByte is your data[])...

```
//convert byte array back to BufferedImage
InputStream in = new ByteArrayInputStream(imageInByte);
BufferedImage bImageFromConvert = ImageIO.read(in);

ImageIO.write(bImageFromConvert, "jpg", 
         new File("c:\\image\\mypic_new.jpg"));
```