# How to upload image on web server?

Tags: java, android, jsp, image-upload

From Android app How to Upload image on web server and how to catch it at server side using jsp ? please help me ?any sample code really helpful...

Comment: I solved my problem by following sol.
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7943262/how-to-display-or-use-an-image-received-from-android-phone-on-the-server

Answer (score 2):

just google it :P

http://www.tutorialspoint.com/jsp/jsp_file_uploading.htm

[how to show an uploaded image on jsp page](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9751598/how-to-show-an-uploaded-image-on-jsp-page)

then ask a question